# Intercept message expiration

Tags: activemq-artemis

Is there a way to catch the message expiration?

I [found](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/intercepting-operations.html) interceptors for incoming and outgoing messages (`remoting-incoming-interceptors` and `remoting-outgoing-interceptors`), but for expiration I did not find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remoting interceptors are only for intercepting protocol-specific input/output between clients and the broker. What you need is a [broker plugin](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/broker-plugins.html). Specifically, you need to implement [`ActiveMQServerMessagePlugin#messageExpired(MessageReference, SimpleString, ServerConsumer)`](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/2.17.0/artemis-server/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/core/server/plugin/ActiveMQServerMessagePlugin.java#L245). When a message expires your plugin will be called.

Of course, a more direct approach would be just to have a listener on a queue bound to the expiry address and the listener will be invoked when a message expires.